# Is there any way to keep touches alive in iOS?

Tags: ios, touch, uitouch

I'm testing the touch detection capabilities of the iPad (specifically iPad 3 at the moment). I'm printing out a log of detected touches to see what is going on, and using a bottle with three foam (touch friendly) pads at the bottom. 
The touches are detected fine and it logs any slight movements which is great. The issue is that after  a while if the bottle isn't moved at all, all three touches are forcibly cancelled and remain undetected until the bottle is removed and placed back down.

So it seems there's a timeout on these touches... I have not found any specific information on this. Is there any way to revive or keep alive touches without having to physically remove and restore your touch points?

Comment: Interesting question! I suppose that there is some low-level control for this, as the device must ultimately detect inactivity...

Comment: It's a weird one, after a lot more testing it doesn't seem to be a timeout kind of thing. At the very least it's not repeatable on the dime. It seems it will simply get rid of the touches. It seems the touch detection works great for short term touches, but isn't reliable enough to be keeping track of long term touches and perform actions when it stops. I think for my purposes I'll be implementing my own detection with an external solution.

Answer (score 0):

A capacitive touch sensor is a very sensitive instrument, and a lot of filtering is done before the OS reports touches to you. This is also the reason why the iPad cannot detect touches with smaller contact areas than what comes with cheap styli - rubber domes of about 7mm diameter. The touchscreen controller detects smaller touches alright, but filters them to avoid spurious signals. Note that the touchscreen of a Samsung Galaxy will already detect touches with a dull pencil - the screen is (for practical purposes) the same as that of an iPad, but the cutoff for the controller is lower.

I would expect that the self-calibrating logic inside the touch controller will calibrate your touches away. Basically, it will set the signal produced by your foam pads as the new normal. On the application side there is nothing that you can do to reverse this.

Disclaimer: I have no inside knowledge of what goes on inside the touchscreen controller. My answer is based on [much](http://www.vagrearg.org/content/capsens1) [reading](http://www.walkermobile.com/SID_2012_Short_Course_S3.pdf) and solid reasoning, nothing more.